# Travis-CI Build error android app

Tags: android, continuous-integration, travis-ci

Im trying to build my Application using Travis-CI. 
But for some reason its constantly giving this error:

```
The command "./gradlew build connectedCheck" exited with 1.
```

This is what is in my .travis.yml:

```
    language: android
    before_install:
      - chmod +x gradlew
    android:
     components:
       - tools 
       - platform-tools
       - build-tools-27.1.1
       - android-27

    script:
     - ./gradlew build connectedCheck
```

Here you got a link to my Travis build:

https://travis-ci.org/Luuk2016/WeatherApp-Android/jobs/371162957

And my build.gradle file:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.district420.weatherapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Hopefully someone can help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your build fails because you have not accepted licenses for Android SDK packages. Add this line to your *travis.yml.*

```
licenses:
  - '.+'
```

**EDIT :**

Since your build now fails due to the error "No connected device". You must create an emulator in the travis and run the instrumentation tests on it.
Add these lines too in the travis.yml file.

```
env:
  global:
    - ANDROID_API_LEVEL=27
    - ANDROID_EMULATOR_LEVEL=21
    - ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=27.0.3
    - ANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a
    - ANDROID_TAG=google_apis
    - ADB_INSTALL_TIMEOUT=20
```

Add these lines to the components section of the travis file.

```
 - android-$ANDROID_EMULATOR_LEVEL
 - sys-img-armeabi-v7a-google_apis-$ANDROID_EMULATOR_LEVEL
```

Add these line too

```
before_script:
# Create and start emulator.
  - echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t "android-"$ANDROID_EMULATOR_LEVEL --abi $ANDROID_ABI --tag $ANDROID_TAG
  - emulator -avd test -no-window &
  - android-wait-for-emulator
  - adb shell input keyevent 82 &
```

Also, add this as the first line of travis.yml

```
sudo: false
```

Comment: Im getting this error: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:connectedDebugAndroidTest'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!

Comment: This is due to another error because you are not creating an emulator in the travis config and you must be having an instrumentation test in your code.

Comment: Could you help me with creating an emulator? Or just give me the code

Comment: Thanks, do i have to place it in a specific order in the file? or can i just paste it all in their? I now got this: https://gyazo.com/a93329987903daacfa1a423d242700ac

Comment: I am not so sure about the order, I guess the order shouldn't matter. However, as a practice, we have the file something like [this](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/blob/master/.travis.yml).

Comment: Cant i just use your .travis.yml you showed my? I think my build i stuck at "Waiting for emulator to start"

Comment: You can use it by changing things as per your requirement. However, the screenshot you showed looks fine to me. You can try running the build with it.

Comment: I just saw that your [build](https://travis-ci.org/Luuk2016/WeatherApp-Android) passed this time :)

Comment: Yes indeed, thank you! 1 last question, is it normal that it takes around 20 minutes?

Comment: Yes creating an emulator is a time taking process. An [Example](https://travis-ci.org/greenrobot/greenDAO/builds/226883788). Could you mark the answer as correct and upvote? It would benefit others too :)

Comment: Ah ok, but isnt that a bit annoying? Everytime you make a commit, a new build will start. I marked it as correct and placed a upvote :D

Comment: Using testdroid helps in reduction of overall build time as the emulator is then not created in travis. PS : I guess you missed the upvote xP

Comment: Because of my reputation it isnt showing up, but its tracked

Comment: Ohh I get it :)

Comment: @HuzaifaIftikhar I am facing similar issue. Can you please check the thread: [Travis build failure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50796889/1650891)